# InertiaJs Manual Visit Not Working Vue3 Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I was facing issue when I manually visit a laravel named route through using inertiaJs router Laravel 9

```
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

router.visit(url, {
  method: 'get',
  data: {},
  replace: false,
  preserveState: false,
  preserveScroll: false,
  only: [],
  headers: {},
  errorBag: null,
  forceFormData: false,
  onCancelToken: cancelToken => {},
  onCancel: () => {},
  onBefore: visit => {},
  onStart: visit => {},
  onProgress: progress => {},
  onSuccess: page => {},
  onError: errors => {},
  onFinish: visit => {},
})
```

Here are [docs](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits)

It Says* undefined function visit*

I solved it using Inertia.visit
`import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'; Inertia.visit(this.route('admin.news', { method: 'get', data: {}, replace: false, preserveState: false, preserveScroll: false, only: [], headers: {}, errorBag: null, forceFormData: false, onCancelToken: cancelToken => {}, onCancel: () => {}, onBefore: visit => {}, onStart: visit => {}, onProgress: progress => {}, onSuccess: page => {}, onError: errors => {}, onFinish: visit => {}, }))`

```
 `import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

router.visit(url, {
    method: 'get',
    data: {},
    replace: false,
    preserveState: false,
    preserveScroll: false,
    only: [],
    headers: {},
    errorBag: null,
    forceFormData: false,
    onCancelToken: cancelToken => {},
    onCancel: () => {},
    onBefore: visit => {},
    onStart: visit => {},
    onProgress: progress => {},
    onSuccess: page => {},
    onError: errors => {},
    onFinish: visit => {},
 })`
```

Comment: this is probably because they have updated inertia. old docs [here](https://legacy.inertiajs.com/manual-visits)

Comment: May be , but I solved it ,